# Can't run pip on python 3.11

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 20.4 install (or really, a reinstall, as I messed up some things and had to start over; everything except `/home` has been reformatted, so if there is an issue with remnants, it's there), with python 3.8 included. However, I want to run python 3.11, since that's the newest. I follow [this guide](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-update-python/), which basically amounts to

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python3.11
```

coupled with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.11 1
```

I now, at least as far as I know, run version 3.11 as default. However, i run into problems with pip. Running just `pip --version` (or `pip3 --version`) returns

```
pip 21.3.1 from /home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

In addition, when I run `python -m pip` (which now uses the 3.11 version) I get

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

If I revert back to `python3.8 -m pip`, I get the welcome message with all the different commands pip has to offer. So that works fine.

(Because deadsnakes has version 3.11 marked as alpha at the moment, I also tried with 3.10. Same result there: no pip.)

I was under the impression that pip came bundled with python as default. How can I give my newer version of python a pip to play with?

Comment: Try to use pip3. For example, pip3 install numpy

Comment: @DanilaMusaev `pip3 --version` still gives the same `pip 21.3.1 from /home/usrname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)` message. `pip3 install numpy` tells me numpy is already installed. `python3.8 -m numpy` complains that numpy isn't executable. `python -m numpy` (with v3.11), on the other hand, tells me I don't have numpy installed.

Comment: Python 3.11 is currently in the early alpha stage of the development. Unless you are taking part in the development process, you should use Python 3.10 as the latest stable release. Really.

Comment: @VPfB Sure. I tried that. I still have the same problem, though: it doesn't have pip.

Comment: @Arthur try to reinstall the pip: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html and use the `--user` option

Comment: @VPfB `/usr/bin/python: No module named ensurepip` is what that gives me. Both with 3.8, 3.10 and 3.11. And trying to install it with `pip install ensurepip` gives `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ensurepip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ensurepip`

Comment: `ensurepip` is a part of the Python installation. If not found, either `/usr/bin/python` is not Python 3.4+, or your installation is corrupted and you have to fix it. In an environment with multiple Python versions like yours, use explicit `/usr/bin/python3.10`

Comment: @VPfB I thought the same about pip. But apparently that's not the case for my installation. `/usr/bin/python` is now 3.10 (I removed 3.11 because, as you said, alpha). But that hasn't solved any of my problems. Is it the deadsnakes repository's fault? Or have I just gotten a bad download? Maybe.

Comment: Strange. Last check: Does `/usr/bin/python -V` display '3.10.0' ? Does `/usr/bin/python -c 'import ensurepip3'` print any errors?

Comment: @VPfB Yes to both. The error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ensurepip3'`.

Comment: @VPfB I tried that too. Same result (only without the `3`)

Comment: I'm afraid I have no more ideas how to help remotely. The import should be successful. I think your Python 3.10 installation is somehow broken. You should have a `/usr/lib64/python3.10/` directory and there should exist an `ensurepip` subdirectory.

Comment: @VPfB I could try to remove the installation and try again. But there is at the moment no python-related directory in `lib64`.

Answer (score 38):

I installed Python3.11 from the deadsnakes ppa, it doesn't come with ensurepip or pip, and the bootstrap script initially fails as it depends on distutils. I solved this by installing the optional distutils package and then bootstrapping.

```sh
apt install python3.11 python3.11-distutils
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11
```

Comment: does not work.  `pip --version` still shows old version of python. what to do ?

Comment: @D.L you probably have multiple versions of Python on your path, try being explicit with `python3.11 -m pip --version` and see if you get the expected result.

Comment: i confirm that this explicit method does work. Although, rather annoying that the user has to specify the python version each time they want to use pip.  Surely pip without a version in front should default (or be aliased) to the latest version... which seems to be the case with windows.

Comment: @D.L This is a property of your environment, not something intrinsic to Python. You can configure it yourself, use your package manager to set defaults for your entire system, or use `pyenv` for a high level of configurability.

Comment: that works thanks, I also added aliases for python and pip to make it easier:

alias python="python3.11"
alias pip="python3.11 -m pip"

Answer (score 21):

```
 sudo apt install python3.11-venv # as ensurepip is not installed at first
 python3.11 -m ensurepip
```

Comment: I'm getting 'ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python'

Comment: @Lefty https://askubuntu.com/questions/879437/ensurepip-is-disabled-in-debian-ubuntu-for-the-system-python

Comment: I got pip after installing venv and I ran module ensurepip.

Answer (score 2):

After downgrading to python 3.10 (because I didn't know 3.11 was still in development) and tinkering with a few commands, including

```
sudo apt install python3.10-pip
```

suddenly it works (I was completely certain I  had tried that already). I also needed

```
sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
```

because pip said I had to. As well as, stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527217/2651045),

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

to stop the

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

error message.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Install Python 3.11 from the deadsnakes PPA:**

```py
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.11
```

2. **Install the `python3.11-distutils` package:**

```py
sudo apt install python3.11-distutils
```

3. **Bootstrap pip for Python 3.11:**

```py
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `alias pip='python3.11 -m pip'`

or make it permanent by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: OP implied that that command doesn't work. So aliasing it won't work either.

Answer (score -2):

i didnt bother trying to install pip separately. since i've successfully installed python3.11, simply do this to install dependencies

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```