# How to fix pip that it points to the correct python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, pygame

So i just installed python3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 and made it default. After that tried to run a program which imports pygame and get an Error `

> " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.base'

After a little bit of research the solution might be

> pip3 uninstall pygame

and to reinstall it, but then i get that error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py)

`which pip3 and which python3 give me 2 different directionaries

Now my question: How do i get them in the same that the pip points at the correct python ?

`

Answer (score 0):

the answer exist in this stack overflow url :[ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70431655/importerror-cannot-import-name-html5lib-from-pip-vendor-usr-lib-python3)

and also you can use something like that for use pip with correct python version, for instanse:

python3 -m pip install <package_name_you_want>