# Creating Virtual Environment with Python 3.11 Returns an Error

Tags: python-venv, python-3.11

I got an error when creating virtualenv with Python 3.11 interpreter.

I typed this in my terminal

```
python3.11 -m venv env
```

It returned this:

```
Error: Command '['/home/bambang/env/bin/python3.11', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What's possibly missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to add `--without-pip` flag. It doesn't return an error so far

Comment: To complete the story, one usually do want 'pip'. So, look at the next step for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527217/1614089

Comment: I have fixed it, brother. I manually download `pip` afterwards, and install it. I have written full article to solve this my way, https://medium.com/@bambang.wirojoyo/setting-up-python-3-11-environment-with-pip-33125a1cf34d

Comment: pip will be missing when you want to install dependencies later, so this is kind of a very temporary workaround.

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo apt install python3.11-venv
```