# Virtual Environment Error with Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, virtual-environment

I'm not sure why I can't create this virtual environment on my Mac. I get an error on a call to python3 in my environment and when I dig in it seems to be looking for something called `ensurepip`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
  $  python3 -m venv venv_test
  Error: Command '['/Users/raysalemi/workspaces/install_mcs_project/venv_test/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  $  /Users/raysalemi/workspaces/install_mcs_project/venv_test/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip
  /Users/raysalemi/workspaces/install_mcs_project/venv_test/bin/python3: No module named ensurepip
  $  pip

  Usage:
    pip <command> [options]
```

Comment: Maybe try `python3 -m venv --without-pip venv_test`

Comment: That worked. Now to figure out what the implications are of no pip and why this happened.  I've installed anaconda3 v 5

Comment: You can install `pip` using the the downloader script once you have activated your venv (`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`).

Comment: Except pip is already installed on my machine with anaconda.  So now I wonder why ensurepip is not working.

Comment: I'd rather `brew install python3` and never used `pip` with the system-provide Python.

Comment: Normally your virtual environment will be completely separate from what is already installed on your system (so if pip is on your system and not in your virtual environment it would need to be installed there as well). It's unclear what the exact issue is, although the resolution in most cases is the solution in my first comment. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24123150/499581

Comment: btw -- if you have multiple python 3.x on your system. You will want "python3.6 -m venv ...."

Comment: @SteveJ same issue.