# python returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, numpy, linux-mint

I try to create a virtual environment to let me install NumPy, SciPy and Matplotlib
I write this: `python3.8 -m venv work3.8`
and the result was: `Error: Command '['/home/mohammed/work3.8/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1), I think you have a same problem.

Comment: it gives another errors

Answer (score 3):

Probably you got the message because the venv package is not present on your system for `python3.8`or that you need `sudo` before the command.

Solve it by installing the venv package for `python3.8`:

```
apt install python3.8-venv
```

Then create a new venv virtual environment:

```
python3.8 -m venv ~/.venvs/work3.8
```

The above assumes that inside your home directory, you have previously created a directory called `.venv`, inside of which the venv virtual environments will be stored. If not, it can be created with `mkdir ~/.venv`

---

***You might need to prepend `sudo` to the commands, depending on what privileges your user has, like so:***

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
sudo python3.8 -m venv ~/.venvs/work3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try: `python3 -m venv [your directory]`

After that, if you want to use your new virtual enviroment type: `source [your directory]/bin/activate`

Then if you want to leave your venv type: `deactivate`

(checked on Debian)

I hope that this helps you,
Kind regards

Comment: I'm new to linux, can you wirte the command with examples

Comment: I write" "python3 -m venv [your directory]"
then: " source[mohammed]/bin/activate"
and the result is: "bash: source[mohammed]/bin/activate: No such file or directory"

Comment: Hello Mohammed,

We create an example folder that will contain our virtual enviroment (venv)
<code> myuser@mypc:~$  mkdir example 
<code> myuser@mypc:~/example$  mkdir venv
Now we create the virtual enviroment inside venv folder:
<code> myuser@fmypc:~/example$  python3 -m venv venv
Now we activate the virtual enviroment:
<code> myuser@mypc:~/example$  source venv/bin/activate
Now the new virtual enviroment is activated:
(venv) myuser@mypc:~/example$  
If we want to leave it just type:
<code>(venv) myuser@mypc:~/example$  deactivate

Comment: The [] means that you need to write the directory where you want to create the virtual enviroment: for example if you want to create the virtualenviroment on the path: /home/mohammed/example

You need you text: ```python3 -m venv /home/mohammed/example```

Do not use the "" please