# How to deal with python virtualenv errors

Tags: python

Hello everyone I am running ubuntu20.4 and have two versions of python on my os
when I try to create the virtual environment with `Python3.9 -m venv venv` or with `python3.8 -m venv venv`  which is the default version it gives me this error and creates the venv folder.

1. How can I use only one version of python on my os?
2. Could you help me understand this error and why am I getting it?

Here is the error that i am getting: `bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: there should be more to that error message. That being said, how about using `virtualenv venv -p python3.9`

Comment: Your error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyvenv-3.4 returned non-zero exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)