# How to download yum packages on windows or from some website?

Tags: python, linux, redhat, python-venv

When creating virtual env via `python3.7 -m venv myenv` I get following error:

```
Error: Command '[/home/..../python3', '-lm', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--deault-pip'] returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This seems to be solved my installing 3 python packages via:
`apt-get/yum install python3.7 python3-venv python3.7-venv` according to [pyvenv-3.4 returned non-zero exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

However My linux server (RHEL 8.4) does not have internet connection therefore I need to download 3 packages mentioned above and then transfer it to the server.

Where can I install them?

- I know I could spin up same os version then download files (last resort)
- I'm aware of websites pkgs.org/, rpmfind.net : I cannot find all 3 packages.

Comment: This seems out of scope for StackOverflow. Maybe you should try one of the other Stack Exchange websites (Super User, Server Fault)