# Cannot properly create a virtual enviroment in Python 3.12

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I use the command line

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

and a new .venv module is created but an error appears:

> Error: Command '['/home/achu/Documentos/portfolio2023/.venv/bin/python3', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1

the bin directory doesn't contain the `activate` file.

I've tried

```
$ apt install python3.12-dev python3.12-venv
```

Comment: error appears when you do what?

Comment: Try other answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1

Comment: @Iskander14yo when command is executed

Comment: try same command with sudo?

Comment: @Iskander14yo Don't use `sudo` unless it's for sysadmin tasks. Never set up a dev environment as root; don't work as root. A bad command can destroy your system.

Comment: *python3 -m venv .venv* works as expected with Python 3.12 on macOS 14.0. The *activate* script is created as expected

Comment: @Robert I am asking for diagnostic purposes. It was not a tip or a solution.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

`sudo apt install python3.12-venv`

and then

`python3.12 -m venv new_venv`

Answer (score 2):

Check if pip installed. Check if you using python3.12, and not other versions of python3.

```
curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.12 get-pip.py
```

Comment: pip is installed and when I check with python3 --version am using python3.12 but I also have python3.10 installed in usr/bin

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Debian testing or derivatives, you can also try:

> sudo aptitude -t testing install python3-pip-whl

This will upgrade the package providing pip, on my setup I got the same error as above due to an too old version of pip was installed.